# how to Fetch dynamic value of texbox inside gridview which is generated in dropdown selected index changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created dynamic `textbox` inside `gridview` which is generated when `dropdown` **selected index changed** but now i want to save that `textbox` value in database but how?

> There, in one row contains five dynamically created textboxes.  Now,
>   how to fetch those `textbox` values on submit button click at each
>   row?

Can any one help me i m new in this field So guide me ...Thanks

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewclass" runat="server" 
OnRowDataBound="GridViewclass_RowDataBound"
OnDataBound="GridViewclass_DataBound"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"
HeaderStyle-BackColor="#174A63" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white" 
AllowPaging="true" Font-Size="14px"
Style="margin-left: 16%;" PageSize="15" Width="300px">
<SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selectedRowStyle" />

<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 4">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 5">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

```
//Code Behind

protected void ddlClassUnits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)    
{
     try
      {
    int createrows = 0;
    int GroupId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlClassUnits.SelectedValue);
    if (GroupId == 0)
    {
        ClearContentControls(4);
    }
    else
    {
        if (GroupId == 1)
        {
            createrows = 1;
        }
        if (GroupId == 2)
        {
            createrows = 2;
        }

        GridViewclass.Visible = true;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column5", typeof(string)));

        for (int i = 0; i < createrows; i++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["RowNumber"] = i + 1; ;
            dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Column4"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Column5"] = string.Empty;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        GridViewclass.DataSource = dt;
        GridViewclass.DataBind();
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read `TextBox` value from `GridView` by using `((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text` statement. 
I've created a `Button` to get value from `GridView` into `DataTable`. Now you can `Insert` those values into `Database`. Please check below example.

Code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column5", typeof(string)));

    DataRow dr = null;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewclass.Rows)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = row.Cells[1].Text;
        dr["Column1"] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
        dr["Column2"] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox2")).Text;
        dr["Column3"] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox3")).Text;
        dr["Column4"] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox4")).Text;
        dr["Column5"] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox5")).Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    //this will insert data of dt into database
    BulkDataInsert(dt, "connectionString");
}

void BulkDataInsert(DataTable dataTable, string connectionString)
{
    try
    {
        SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock)
        {
            DestinationTableName = txtTableName.Text,
            BatchSize = 100000,
            BulkCopyTimeout = 360
        };
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);

        //Data Inserted Succesfull
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //ex.Message)
    }
}
```

I've created a method `BulkDataInsert`, this will insert full `DataTable` into `Database`. You need to pass `DataTable` and **Connection String** of your `Database`.

Output:[image]

Comment: Thanks I m using it then i say....At present time in my system VS gonna currupt so i wll use that after few hours then i will  reply you....Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you guide me .. In gridview suppose we have five rows and i want to insert this five rows into database at one time insertion not five times hit insert query. Thanks .

Comment: Yes, you can use `SqlBulkCopy` to `insert` full `DataTable` into `Database`.

Comment: Please check **TransferData** method in [Transfer data or script between two SQL Server databases](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/490448/Transfer-data-or-script-between-two-SQL-Server-dat) article.

Comment: @amitkumar, did you checked the article for `SqlBulkCopy`?

Comment: OK i m check ....Thanks if u dont mind Actuall i m new in this field and when task is assigned to me in office then i am doing but its get late to complete and boss will be blame ...Actually i cant handle it ,i want to do it but i cant understand what we do in that task which is assigned to me and how we do ...Its getting more problem i cant understand that basics i m studying fro google or some where but i cant understand...Can u suggest me or Guide me to Teach Asp.Net ...Thanks a Lot for Helping Me